# Why do the electrons on a charged surface not accelerate away from each other?

Tags: electromagnetism

This question was asked to me by a 'backyard scientist' and I'm having a frustrating difficulty answering it satisfactorily.

As an example of a charged object to focus attention on, I'll use this bench-top [Van de Graaff generator](https://physlab.lums.edu.pk/images/d/d8/VDG_final.pdf) (VDG):

[image: Van de Graaff schematic]

The metal sphere is $0.25\:\mathrm{m}$ diameter, rated maximum voltage $375,000\:\mathrm{V}$ and maximum charge $5.2\:\mathrm{\mu C}$.

Based on this, I made a few 'back of an envelope' calculations and estimates for this VDG, at max. charge:

Number of electrons on the sphere $= \frac{5.2 \times 10^{-6}}{1.6\times 10^{-19}}=3.25\times 10^{13}$

Surface area of the sphere = $\pi D^2=\pi \times (0.25)^2=0.20\:\mathrm{m^2}$

Estimated distance between electrons (square packing) = $\sqrt\frac{0.2}{3.25\times 10^{13}}=7.8\times10^{-8}\:\mathrm{m}$

Repulsive force between two adjacent electrons (Coulomb's Law)$=9\times10^{9}\times\frac{(1.6\times 10^{-19})^2}{(7.8\times10^{-8})^2}=3.8\times10^{-14}\:\mathrm{N}$

Electron acceleration due to repulsive force: $F=ma$:

$a=\frac{3.8\times10^{-14}}{9.1\times10^{-31}}=4.2\times10^{16}\:\mathrm{ms^{-2}}$

That's quite a whopper! Hard to see how these electrons would not fly away from each other (and reduce their potential energy).

I found this [P.S answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/233427/why-cant-electrons-leave-negatively-charged-objects-in-a-vaccum) to a very similar question but don't find it very satisfying.

What am I missing?

Comment: They're pulled back in by the atomic nuclei.

Comment: Can you clarify why "attraction by protons" and "work function" from the other answer don't satisfy you?

Comment: You're also forgetting that the force that an electron feels is due to the sum of the electric fields from _all_ of the electrons, not just one.

Comment: @knzhou what?? electrons

Comment: @Jasper: for one, steel contains almost no protons.

Comment: @probably_someone: no, I was just simplifying by focusing on adjacent electrons.

Comment: @Gert Then you have to take into account _all_ of the adjacent electrons. The electric field basically cancels everywhere due to the presence of neighboring electrons on all sides.

Comment: Steel contains a truckload of protons. Usually one for each electron.

Comment: @Jasper: sorry, I was thinking like a chemist  there. LOL.

Comment: @Gert "Steel contains no protons"?!

Comment: @knzhou: see the comment above yours. Yes of course all materials contain protons, embedded in the material's nuclei.

Comment: speaking of protons, this is relevant in  a way https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator . protons are really tied to the lattice.

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is the fact that each electron is affected not only by a single electron adjacent to it, but by all of the other electrons surrounding it as well.

The repulsive force of the electrons will cause them to spread evenly across the surface. Once this has happened, each electron will feel an approximately equal force from all of its neighbours, resulting in a net force close to zero.

Note: Electrons will obviously still feel some net force perpendicular to the surface, but unless the total charge is extremely high, this won't be anywhere near enough to strip the electrons from the material.

Comment: *each electron will feel an approximately equal force from all of its neighbours,* How can that be when some are close to a given electron and some very far away?

Comment: If an electron is closer to some of its neighbours than others, then it will be pushed away from the ones it is close to. Once it has moved, it will then be nearer to the ones on the other side, and they will push it back, and so on. Eventually you will reach a state in which all of the electrons are oscillating about equilibrium points which are roughly equidistant to their neighbours.

Comment: If that were true, that would happen in all directions, forming a gas of electrons, as they fell even less force from neighbours by escaping away.  You're missing the key point: they are bounded to the atoms.

Comment: @Katie: sorry, but this is not the explanation. If the reason would be the balance of the repulsive forces due to other electrons, it would not  be understandable why electrons on a convex piece of metals are not ejected from the metal, since there would be a non equilibrated component of the force pushing them out of the metal. The real reason is in the presence of an energy barrier, due to quantum mechanics, which requires a finite energy to be overcome (see work function ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function ).

Comment: @GiorgioP: maybe you should formulate an answer to that effect?

Comment: @GiorgioP: I was taking it for granted that the electrons would all stay *on* the surface of the metal, as it seems obvious that the net force exerted perpendicular to the surface would not typically be enough to strip the electrons from the material. I was focusing on explaining why electrons confined to an enclosed surface don't fly around at crazy velocities on that surface, which is what it seemed like OP was actually asking about.

Comment: @GiorgioP I am not sure the OP is asking about why excess electrons do not fly off of charged surfaces

Comment: @Katie: if electrons confined to an enclosed surface fly around at crazy velocities they  would increase their kinetic energy, not their potential energy (see the final part of the question).  Side remark: if you were referring to me, I did not downvote your answer. I only wrote the above comment.